# PHP: Insert database value into different php array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have 2 datepicker in my page "From" and "To". User will select date for each value:

```
FromDate: 01/JUL/2012     ToDate: 31/OCT/2014
```

And this is my query:

```
  $query = mssql_query("SELECT count(startdate) as start
                        FROM user 
                        WHERE startdate between '01 JUL 2012' and '31 OCT 2014' 
                        GROUP BY  month(startdate), year(startdate) 
                        ORDER BY  month(startdate) ASC, year(startdate) ASC");
```

I want to count all records that range from the user selected date, group it by year and month and store it in php array.

Example Result:

```
          JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
```

`Array2012 = ("52","45","25","62","11","41")`

```
          JAN  FEB  MAR   DEC
```

`Array2013 = ("52","45","25",......,"35")`

```
         JAN  FEB  MAR   OCT
```

`Array2014 = ("52","45","25",.......,"47")`

How can I loop the values from database so I can get those results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a couple of things :

- Add year in your select fields and use it to insert your result in the array
- Change your order by : sort by year first, then month

In result, code will look like this :

```
$values = array();
$lastYear = 0;

$query = mssql_query("SELECT count(startdate) as start, 
                    year(startdate) AS year
                    FROM user 
                    WHERE startdate between '01 JUL 2012' and '31 OCT 2014' 
                    GROUP BY  month(startdate), year(startdate) 
                    ORDER BY  year(startdate) ASC, month(startdate) ASC");

while ($data = mssql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($data['year'] != $lastYear) {
        $lastYear = $data['year'];
        $values[$data['year']] = array();
    }
    array_push($values[$data['year']], $data['start']);
}

print_r($values);
```

$values will contain :

```
Array(
[2012] => Array("52","45","25","62","11","41"}),
[2013] => Array("52","45","25",......,"35"),
[2014] => Array("52","45","25",.......,"47")
)
```

Comment: That was fast reply.. Thanks.. I will try it later and tell you the result.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: how to print the results.. i've tried what you said and it results me nothing, the page is blank..

Comment: You can use print_r($values); to show what is stored in the array

Comment: it prints blank.. oh, i see now, in array_push, it should be $data['start'].. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this code snippet to loop through the return values from the db query:

```
$query = mssql_query("SELECT count(startdate) as start
                    FROM user 
                    WHERE startdate between '01 JUL 2012' and '31 OCT 2014' 
                    GROUP BY  month(startdate), year(startdate) 
                    ORDER BY  month(startdate) ASC, year(startdate) ASC");
    if($query == FALSE){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $row['startdate']
    }
```

Hope I understood you correctly and that I could help.

Peace

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that kind of loop and it worked for me but i dont know how can i store the value in different array.